# Flash AS3 load and replace movie

Tags: actionscript-3, loading

I have a loader mc...an animation that loops - when you click a button I want a new movie to load on top and replace the loader mc

Here is my current code:

```
btn_load.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_load_press);
function btn_load_press(e:MouseEvent)
{
    var reloadRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("new-movie.swf");
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(reloadRequest);
    addChild(loader);
}
```

But this puts it on top on my loader...effectively meaning the loader is still running in the background.

This is really simple in AS2 - and I'm not sure if it's even possible in AS3

Comment: have you tried `removeChild(mc);`?

Comment: Where would that go?...and what is (mc)?

Comment: whats your looping animation called, I'll write this up as a proper answer

Comment: It's just loader.swf - that's where the above code is that opens the new-movie.swf - thanks

Comment: ok so what is "I have a loader mc...an animation that loops"?

Comment: I have loader.swf - within that is a looping animation and a button with the above code - the button is supposed to launch the main movie and remove the looping animation.

Comment: does the looping animation have an `id` or no?

Comment: It doesn't no - i can give it an instance name if need be

Comment: would be helpful otherwise we cant remove it specifically and would have to remove everything bar the `"new-movie.swf"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56523/discussion-between-alib0ng0-and-cyanangel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this we'll need to add a listener for your `loader.contentLoaderInfo`s complete event, then remove your animation once everything has finished loading.

```
btn_load.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_load_press);
function btn_load_press(e:MouseEvent)
{
    var reloadRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("new-movie.swf");
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loader_complete);
    loader.load(reloadRequest);
    addChild(loader);
}
function loader_complete(e:Event)
{
    e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loader_complete);
    removeChild(loader_mc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm getting this....Scene 1, Layer 'as', Frame 1, Line 12 1120: Access of undefined property event...

Comment: my bad, typo in the answer